Is there a way to have 1 coupon with 4 different values
I am looking for an solution that with which i can do the following:
I want to use 1 coupon code for this.
If Subtotal (Excl. Tax) exeeds € 1500,- then give 2.5% reduction over the whole cart.
If Subtotal (Excl. Tax) exeeds € 2500,- then give 3.0% reduction over the whole cart.
If Subtotal (Excl. Tax) exeeds € 3250,- then give 3.5% reduction over the whole cart.
If Subtotal (Excl. Tax) exeeds € 3750,- then give 4.0% reduction over the whole cart
Is this possible or must i look to another solution?

In Magento 2, you can't directly create a single coupon code with multiple discount rates based on the cart subtotal.
However, you can achieve this by creating multiple cart price rules with the same coupon code but different conditions and discount rates.
Here's a step-by-step guide:

Navigate to Marketing > Cart Price Rules in the Magento admin panel.
Click on "Add New Rule".
Fill in the required fields such as Rule Name, Description, and Websites.
In the "Coupon" dropdown, select "Specific Coupon" and enter your desired coupon code.
Set the "Conditions" to "Subtotal equals or greater than 1500".
Set the "Actions" to "Percent of product price discount" and set the "Discount Amount" to 2.5.
Save and apply the rule.
Repeat the steps for the other discount rates, changing the conditions and discount amount accordingly.

Remember to set the priority of the rules correctly. The rule with the highest subtotal should have the highest priority, so it gets applied first. If it doesn't apply, Magento will move to the next rule.
Please note that this solution will apply the highest applicable discount to the cart. If the subtotal is €4000, it will apply the 4.0% discount, not all the discounts cumulatively.
I haven't tried it but you should give it a try.
